# What purposes do vehicle registration renewals serve in the United States?

Tags: united-states, taxes, public-administration

Any reasons other than collecting $50 per year per vehicle (which is essentially a tax) would be appreciated.

Comment: Some regions also require emissions testing for renewal. But yea, it's mainly a tax to pay for things.

Comment: I remember the days of $50 registration... Must have been 20 ish years ago though.  was 300 for one 190 for another and 150 for my Bike this year

Comment: @DA I think that juxtaposes "registration" with "inspection"... while the two are often related, they are different concepts.  An "inspection" serves a public order/ safety function, which emissions can comfortably fit in.  "Registration" is pretty much exclusively a tax for the privilege of owning/ operating a vehicle in a particular state, although it also is tied to license plating and whatnot.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, part of the purpose for vehicle registration is for taxation.

Another thing that vehicle registration does is it establishes clear ownership of the vehicle (because you don't always keep it on your person.)  It's kinda like the deed to your house.

It can come in handy in-case someone steals your car, or if you somehow lose your car otherwise.  It becomes easier to track.

It also Identifies you, in-case you break some sort of traffic law, your license plate can be noted, and the government will be able to find whoever owns a particular car.

---

The reason you have to renew, is because it's easier to keep track of a vehicle if its registration keeps getting renewed.  If the owner doesn't keep renewing it, It's very difficult to  know whether the vehicle still exists, or if the owner (improperly) sold it without transferring ownership etc...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration

Comment: Re: ownership proof, the question was about renewal, not registration itself

Comment: @DVK - But if you do not have to register every year you just sell your car with original registration and then when someone does a hit and run with your old car, that has been sold 3 or 4 times since you owned it, they come to you because "your" car was used in a hit and run.

Comment: @Chad - There's a difference between registering a NEW car on change of ownership (which is typically **NOT** referred to as **renewal** of registration) and registering again (every 2 years, at least in some states) for the same exact car.

Comment: @DVK - If you do not have to pay for registration unless you buy a car why would you bother to register a car that has already been registered?  I personally do no feel like spending $50 I do not have to let alone the $300 it cost me for my edge.  And since it isn't yearly expect it to be closer to 1k.

Comment: I live in MA, ownership is established by "title". Registration is another document which proves that you have insurance and a license plate. I don't mind paying the first $50 to get the license plate and the registration paper, but I was trying to comprehend the reason behind yearly $50 registration renewal. In MA, when you sell a car, the title has to be transferred, and a new registration has to be acquired, too.

Comment: @Chad - in NJ, by law you MUST renew registration every 2 years - it has nothing to do with car changes and only the expiration date on your registration. If you don't, you have expired registration (which I assume is treated as having no registration by police but never bothered to check).

Comment: @Mr.TA - If you did not need to get the registration then why would you bother to pay the title transfer fee.  Just keep the signed title and give it to the next person you sell it.  Now you do not have to pay the title fee or the registration fee.  So a few years after you sold your car it is still in your name in title and registration because the people who bought it did not want to have to pay the fees.  So a renewal fee forces you to get a new registration which requires a title in the name of the person registering the vehicle.

Comment: It's easier to keep track of the vehicle and the owner when the owner has to keep renewing his registration.

Comment: @Chad quite the opposite, I did need to get the registration, after having to pay title transfer fee, and I do need now to renew the registration (but not the title) every year, for $50. You're describing a scenario in which the seller would allow the buyer to continue driving on the same license plate and consequently on the same insurance. This is highly unlikely, to say the least, because the seller has no reason to pay for buyer's insurance and to be subjected to premium increase risks. The seller usually takes the license plates off the car upon sale and returns it to DMV right away.

Comment: @Mr.TA - It is fairly common for people in the US to drive with out valid plate/licence/ or insurance.  That one reason why the costs for insurance are so high.  If you do not need to register the car there is no incentive for those who would ignore the law to pay the other costs (title/registration/insurance) since all they have to do is avoid being pulled over by a cop that will not accept that I borrowed this car from my friend.  And unless the car is reported stolen the cop has no cause to investigate further.

Comment: @Chad good to know. But still, registration renewal doesn't really stop that from happening, because if someone is risking getting a huge bouquet of tickets/charges for no insurance, invalid/stolen plates,  and no license, what is a $50 annual fee going to do to convince them to change their ways?

Comment: @Mr.TA - The comments are in response to the question of how would it establish chain of ownership.  The registration belongs to you, is transferable to your vehicle and you are responsible for registering the vehicle.  If the vehicle is not registered there are not legal plates which is a red flags for the police to pull over.

Comment: @Chad I think there's a misunderstanding here. Ownership is established by title; it's in my best interest to transfer the ownership to my name, by acquiring a new title, to get the protection of the law in case anyone were to lay a claim to my vehicle. Whether some people in US break the law or not, or pursue their interests or not, is irrelevant - who am I to judge others' choices. My question was about the law. The license plates help police identify cars on the road, which is a valid requirement. The registration paper and especially its renewal, on the other hand, does not help anything.

Comment: @Mr.TA - What is your point... get to it please.  If you do not have plates teh police have cause to pull you over and check registration.

Comment: @Chad I understand the plates. What purpose does the registration piece of paper serve in my glovebox? And even more importantly, why is paying $50 every 2 years to renew it needed?

Comment: @Mr.TA - The vehicle could be leased.  You still have to register that vehicle that you do not own.  they want to know who is legally responsible for that vehicle and who they can expect to be in the vehicle if they pull it over.  And the answer covers why you have to pay for it

Comment: @SoylentGray The way it works in the UK now, is that cameras on police cars automatically photograph registration plates. A computer checks each one and feeds back to a monitor in the police vehicle any that do not have up-to-date registration, legal insurance, and a current MOT safety inspection certificate. The result is that police are instantly aware of a vehicle close to them that is unsafe or uninsured. Also an unregistered vehicle is often a lead into the discovery of something far more serious going on. And it gives the police reason to interview the driver.

Comment: @Mr.TA The piece of paper in your glovebox is not the most important part of registration renewal (as that information is also in a central state computer database). Registration renewal also includes an expiration date sticker for your plates that lasts until the registration needs to be renewed. If it's expired you are ticketed and must update the contact information, emissions certification, insurance certification, and current ownership of record of the vehicle making it much more likely that all of those obligations are complied with in a manner that is easy for traffic cops to enforce.

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked 6 years ago but for whatever reason has come back up in the Top Questions list so I will answer it as no one else has properly.  The asker of the question wanted

> "Any reasons other than collecting $50 per year per vehicle (which is essentially a tax)",

but no other reason exists.  The registration renewal with accompanying fee is used to raise funds for transportation maintenance such as road repair and construction.  You can read a little more about how it works in Texas here:
[How it works: Where do fees from vehicle registration and inspection go?](https://communityimpact.com/houston/tomball-magnolia/features/2018/04/04/how-it-works-where-do-fees-from-vehicle-registration-and-inspection-go-3/)